# Using a model clean function to validate additional fields in admin form

Tags: python, django, validation

I'm using [pickelField](https://github.com/shrubberysoft/django-picklefield) in my model to serialize csv data into the database as a pandas dataframe.
Pickle field does not display on the admin form so I created an additional text field.

I'm following [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20120828045035/http://www.hindsightlabs.com/blog/2010/02/11/adding-extra-fields-to-a-model-form-in-djangos-admin/) example of adding custom fields to the admin form.

```
class ParameterDataTableAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # create field to accept csv text
    data = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ParameterDataTable

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ParameterDataTableAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # if instance exists this is an update
        if kwargs.has_key('instance'):
            instance = kwargs['instance']         
            # repr existing data
            csv_text = StringIO()
            instance.values.to_csv(csv_text,index=False)
            self.initial['data'] = csv_text.getvalue()

    def save(self, commit=True):
        model = super(ParameterDataTableAdminForm, self).save(commit=False)
        # convert the data to a pandas data frame
        model.values = pandas.read_csv(StringIO(self.cleaned_data['data']))

        # NEED TO VALIDATE MODEL.VALUES

        if commit:
            model.save()

        return model

class ParameterDataTableAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ParameterDataTableAdminForm

admin.site.register(ParameterDataTable, ParameterDataTableAdmin)
```

Problem is that `model.values` is being added to the model after the clean method ran. I want to use the models clean method to validate the field. for obvious reasons I'm trying to avoid validation of model fields in the admin form.

I've tried explicitly running `model.clean` right after setting `model.values` but i get an exception and not a clean nice error message on the screen.

What is the best way to validate the field `value` using the model's clean method and associate it with the form field `values` ?

**EDIT** - I'm adding the relevant parts of my model

```
class ParameterDataTable(ParameterBase):
    values = PickledObjectField(null=False, blank=False, verbose_name=_("values"))

    def clean(self):
        super(ParameterDataTable, self).clean()
        if self.is_visible:
            raise ValidationError(_("Datatable cannot be visible"))

        if pd.isnull(self.values).any().any():
           raise ValidationError(_("Found missing values."))
```

*I'm using PolymorphicModel for my models. `ParameterBase` is a PolymorphicModel. I Haven't had any trouble with that.*

Comment: Can you show your model?

Comment: So you have CSV data and you're storing it as pickle data?  Is there a problem with storing it as CSV data?

Comment: You save data once but you use it over and over again - I rather do the conversion at creation rather doing it every time I access the data.

Comment: It's still a pickled dataframe which requires conversion to a dataframe object before you can use it though, right?  I see there is also a read_json() function available in pandas, you could store the data as JSON, which should display fine in the admin.

Comment: I thought of using JSON to store the data but I came to a conclusion that it might effect my ability in the future to handle big data sets. I also looked into the possibility of using HDF5 store but I ended up deciding to go use database storage using a pickled field. This admin form is a small bit of the solution and I don't want it to dictate my design.

Comment: ok, I can understand if you're stuck with using CSV for whatever reason.  Just trying to think of ways to make this easier.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating an additional field on the form, just create a custom form Field for your `values` model field and handle the conversion in this custom field:

```
def validate_pandas_frame(value):
    if pd.isnull(value).any().any():
        raise ValidationError(_("Found missing values."))

class CSVTextarea(forms.Textarea):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        csv_text = StringIO()
        output = value.to_csv(csv_text, index=False)
        return super(CSVTextarea, self).render(name, output, attrs)

class PickledCSVField(forms.Field):
    widget = CSVTextarea
    default_validators = [validate_pandas_frame]
    def to_python(self, value):
        return pandas.read_csv(StringIO(value))



class ParameterDataTableAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # create field to accept csv text
    values = forms.PickledCSVField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ParameterDataTable

    ...
```

Edit: Added a custom `forms.Textarea` implementation for the conversation **to** CSV for the form rendering.

Comment: Hey @Kevin, Thanks for the answer. I insist on using the model's clean function because i'm getting data from different sources and I want to keep the validation in one place. using your suggestion i'm "out sourcing" the validation from the model to the form, and not only the form but specifically the admin form. If i'll want to receive csv data from, lets say, an API I would have to validate it somewhere else.

Comment: Models shouldn't be concerned with input/output. That's the point of forms to handle that conversion. They can share validators as I've shown with a separate validators. Your eventual API layer will need a similar construct to forms to handle serialization/deserialization (called Serializers in django rest framework for example).

Answer (score 0):

Just  an idea, but you may be able to pre-assign the model's values in the ModelForm's `clean()` method, instead of trying to do it in the `save()` method.

That way ValidationErrors should propagate neatly up to the admin.

```
class ParameterDataTableAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # create field to accept csv text
    data = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ParameterDataTable

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ParameterDataTableAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # if instance exists this is an update
        if kwargs.has_key('instance'):
            instance = kwargs['instance']         
            # repr existing data
            csv_text = StringIO()
            instance.values.to_csv(csv_text,index=False)
            self.initial['data'] = csv_text.getvalue()


    def clean(self):
        # clean to initially populate cleaned_data
        super(ParameterDataTableAdminForm, self).clean()  

        # parse cleaned_data and assign resulting pickled dataframe to values
        self.instance.values = pandas.read_csv(StringIO(self.cleaned_data['data']))            

        # run clean again, to catch values errors
        # or, even try, self.instance.clean()
        super(ParameterDataTableAdminForm, self).clean()
```

It's a hard find, but the model instance is available under `instance` in the ModelForm.

> A model form instance bound to a model object will contain an instance
>   attribute that gives its methods access to that specific model
>   instance.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-clean-method

Comment: Its failing during clean with `argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable`. The instance hasent been populated yet at that point - is it even possible to set values there ?

Comment: ok, I suspect that means that `self.cleaned_data` isn't populated yet, which would make sense...  It's not pretty, but would it work if you added a call to clean before the values assignment?